# approaching $\int \sqrt{x^5+2}\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I recently came across this integral $\int\sqrt{x^5+2}\; dx$. From [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sqrt%28x%5E5%2B2%29&t=crmtb01) i can see that it has a closed form. how does one get to that closed form? what techniques should i approach?

Comment: Yeah but i dont have pro. And also how can i know what to do? To solve theese normaly

Comment: Think you should read the problem again :)

Comment: The solution is in terms of a hypergeometric function which should indicate that a series approach is being used.

Comment: The thing im woundering about is how do i find that series? what should i use to find it etc? and get to that final solution.

Comment: You could find the general term in the Taylor Series expansion of $\sqrt{x^5+2}$ then integrate that.

Comment: so according to WolframAlpha, taylor series is $\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{-1^{\frac{5+n}{5}}2^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{5}}\left(-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{n}{5}\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi }\:\frac{n}{5}!}$ and by integrating that i just get $\int \sum _{n=-\infty \:}^{\infty \:}-\frac{2^{\frac{-5-2n}{10}}\frac{-15+2n}{10}!}{\sqrt{\pi }\frac{n}{5}!}$, where do i go from this?

Comment: Sorry about all that lol, deleted my answer

Comment: @CameronWilliams. The result from WA does not seem to be correct. Would you check ? Thanks & cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, using Taylor or the binomial theorem, we have
$$\sqrt{x^5+2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{  \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)!}{
  2^n\, n!} x^{5 n}$$
$$\int \sqrt{x^5+2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{  \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)!}{
  2^n\,(5n+1)\, n!} x^{5 n+1}$$ Computing the infinite summation
$$S=x\sqrt{2}  \,\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{5};\frac{6}{5};-\frac{x^5}{2}\right)$$ which looks simpler that the result from Wolfram Alpha but which numerically does not agree with it. However, the formula given here matches the results obtained by numerical integration.

What happens ? That is the question !

**Edit**

If I use the result given by Wolfram Alpha,
$$\int \sqrt{x^5+2}\,dx=\frac{1}{7} x \left(5 \sqrt{2} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{2};\frac{6}{5};-\frac{x^5}{2}\right)+2   \sqrt{x^5+2}\right)$$ and differentiate is, hoping that I am not mistaken, the result is 
$$\frac{5 x^5}{2 \sqrt{x^5+2}}$$

On Wolfram Cloud, I obtained the result I gave.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What im really trying to understand by all this is how to go from $\int \sqrt{x^5+2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{  \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)!}{
  2^n\,(5n+1)\, n!} x^{5 n+1}$ and then to $S=x\sqrt{2}  \,\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{5};\frac{6}{5};-\frac{x^5}{2}\right)$